# Ajax succes working but not sending data to mysql database on.click function and not working completely with on.submit

Tags: php, jquery

My problem is that when I click the submit button while I have a on.('click') on top of my jQuery ajax, success works but doesn't send information to my database. Otherwise when I have on.('submit') on top of my jQuery the ajax doesn't work but PHP does.

Here is the code of my form.

```
<div id="seccion_registro">
<div id="login_error">Campo no valido!</div>
<div id="registro_succes"></div>


            <form id="form2" name="form2" action="usuario.php" method="POST">
                <label for="nombre">Nombre</label>
                <input id="nombre"type="text" class="text" size="20" name="nombre">

                <label for="usuario">Usuario</label>
                <input id="password1" type="text" class="text" size="20" name="usuario">

                <label for="contrasena">Contraseña</label>
                <input id="password1" type="password" class="text" size="20" name="contrasena">

                <label for="confirmar">Confirmar contraseña</label>
                <input id="password2" type="password" class="text" size="20" name="confirmar">

                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class= "text" size="20" name="email">

        <div>
                <input type="submit" class="boton1" value="Regístrate" size="56">
        </div>
 </form>
```

This is my jquery ajax function, i use a fancybox to display the form and a succes or error response.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

$('.boton1').on('click', function(e){


e.preventDefault();

var name = $('#nombre').val();
var password1 = $('#password1').val();
var password2 = $('#password2').val();
var errors = '';

if(name.length < 5 || name == ''){
errors += '<p>tsads</p>'; 
} 




if(errors != ''){    
$("#login_error").show();       
$.fancybox.resize();

//$("#login_succes").hide();

} else {
var datos = $('#form2').serialize();
$.ajax({
    url:'Usuario.php',
    data:'datos',
    type:'POST',
    beforeSend: function(){
          $('#seccion_registro').html('<div id="carga" style="margin:0 auto;width:auto;background-position:center center;"></div>');
        },
    success: function(){
         $('#seccion_registro').html('<p class="text_enhorabuena">Enhorabuena, has sido registrado!</p>');
        $("#registro_succes").show();       
        $.fancybox.resize();
}
 });

 }



 });
```

And finally this is my PHP script.

```
<?php

include 'conexion.php';

$_POST['nombre'];
$_POST['usuario'];
$_POST['contrasena'];
$_POST['email'];

$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario (Usuario, password, email, nombre ) VALUES ('".$_POST['usuario']."', 
  '".$_POST['contrasena']."', '".$_POST['email']."', '".$_POST['nombre']."')";


if (!mysqli_query($conexion,$consulta))
  {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($conexion));
  }
else{

//Do stuff

};
mysqli_close($conexion);

?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Sending Requests

Take a look at this:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2" action="usuario.php" method="POST">
```

With this you are telling our browsers that when the user clicks the submit button send all the form variables to `usuario.php`. And you have a script that does exactly the same.

So you are sending the form data with two ways: HTML and Jquery.

I suggest you to use only one way to send data to `usuarios.php`, and maybe things get a little clearer. For instance, change the form tag to this:

```
<form id="form2" name="form2">
```

No method, and no action, because that stuff jQuery will take care of.

And then check if everything works.

### Jquery

Change the `$('.boton1').on('click', function(e){`

For `$('#form2').on('submit', function(e){`

### Also check the things you are sending

Look at your Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'Usuario.php',
    data:'datos',
```

I think it should be like this:

```
$.ajax({
    url:'Usuario.php',
    data:datos,
```

(Check the `datos` variable)

### Mysql Injection

If everything went OK, next step is to prevent mysql injection. I see you are using `mysqli`, but you are not using prepared statements! So there is a possibility you are open to mysql injection attacks.

Change to prepared statements:

```
/* crear una sentencia preparada */
$consulta = "INSERT INTO usuario (Usuario, password, email, nombre ) VALUES ('?','?', '?', '?')";

if ($stmt = mysqli_prepare($link, $consulta)) {
    /* ligar parámetros para marcadores */
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "ssss", $_POST['usuario'],$_POST['contrasena'],$_POST['email'],$_POST['nombre']);

/* ejecutar la consulta */
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
}
```

To view more information about prepared statements: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php

Comment: Tomás is correct. If you have a submit button, then you need to do e.preventDefault();, but a regular button will do nothing when clicked, which is why you add the jQuery to the click event. You really can't use both together, and you don't want to. You either want to submit the form or have the button and jQuery do the same thing without submitting the form.

Comment: Thank you very much, the only problem i had was that i was treating the data variable as a string and it was a variable. It was datos and not 'datos', a very silly mistake. I shouldn't drink so much vodka next time. :D